Redux Toolkit Query (RTKQ) endpoint invalidation and revalidate fires multiple times
To preface this I have looked in Redux-Toolkit documentation for this and have not found the answer to this issue through injecting endpoints and code splitting. I don't know if this is a bug but will also be posting in the Github for RTK as well.
Problem: When you use RTK mutation and have multiple injectEndpoints, the revalidation of a GET (Query) is fired multiple times. I have multiple injectEndpoints as I want separation of each of my endpoints. What I am seeing is for every separate file with injectEndpoint in it RTK is fetching additional for each file.
Expected: When you fire a RTK mutation the revalidation of any GET (Query) should only fire 1 time regardless of how many injectEndpoints are in the API. This was the behavior when RTK was first introduced.
Code:
store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

// API
import { baseQuery } from 'api/baseQuery'
import { commentsApi } from 'api/commentsApi'
import { postApi } from 'api/postApi'

const reducer = {
  [baseQuery.reducerPath]: baseQuery.reducer,
  [commentsApi.reducerPath]: commentsApi.reducer,
  [postApi.reducerPath]: postApi.reducer
}

const middleware = getDefaultMiddleware =>
  getDefaultMiddleware()
  .concat(baseQuery.middleware)
  .concat(commentsApi.middleware)
  .concat(postApi.middleware)

export const store = configureStore({
  middleware,
  reducer
})

baseQuery.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const baseQuery = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    prepareHeaders: headers => {
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
      return headers
    }
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  reducerPath: 'api',
  tagTypes: [
    'comments',
    'posts'
  ]
})

postApi.js
import { baseQuery } from './baseQuery'

export const postApi = baseQuery.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: ({ mutation, query }) => ({
    addPost: mutation({
      invalidatesTags: ['posts'],
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/posts`
      })
    }),
    getPosts: query({
      providesTags: ['posts'],
      query: () => `/posts`
    }),
  })
})

export const {
  useAddPostMutation,
  useGetPostsQuery
} = postApi

commentsApi.js
import { baseQuery } from './baseQuery'

export const commentsApi = baseQuery.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: ({ mutation, query }) => ({
    getComments: query({
      providesTags: ['comments'],
      query: () => `/posts/1/comments`
    }),
  })
})

export const {
  useGetCommentsQuery
} = commentsApi

App.js
import { Button, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import ChevronLeftRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeftRounded'
import { useAddPostMutation, useGetPostsQuery } from 'api/postApi'
import { useGetCommentsQuery } from 'api/commentsApi'

const App = () => {
  const { data = [] } = useGetPostsQuery()
  const { data: comments = []} = useGetCommentsQuery()
  const [addPost] = useAddPostMutation()

  console.log('comments', comments)

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={addPost}
        startIcon={<ChevronLeftRoundedIcon />}
      >
        Add Post
      </Button>
      <Stack
        spacing={3}
        sx={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          px: 3
        }}
      >
        <Typography>
          List of Posts
        </Typography>
        {data.map(({ id, title }) => (
          <Typography key={id} variant='body2'>
            {title}
          </Typography>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from 'store/store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

Only dependencies here are Redux, Redux-Toolkit, Material-UI, Ramda. I am utilizing the jsonplaceholder API as a simple example here so you can easily replicate this issue.
What is happening

As you look in the network tab you'll get your initial GET for the posts & comments endpoints
Click the "Add Post" button
Fires off the POST to the posts endpoint
Network tab fires off GET to the posts endpoint 3 times
1 201 POST
3 200s GET, without the comments endpoint injected this returns 2 200s GET. Meaning that for every injected endpoint there is an additional GET happening

NOTE:
I do not have the react app in strict mode, as this will not have any effect on the end results. It looks as though every GET is re-rendering the App.js component, but the Redux Store should not be causing this issue. In previous applications using Redux and RTK you could easily write the app like this and never see multiple GETs fired for every Mutation you used.
Images of the issue:

Before button click


After button click




Even though you are code-splitting you still only have one API slice that you are "extending/enhancing".
I'm nearly certain your issue is being caused by adding what are effectively "duplicate" API slices, each of commentsApi and postApi "extend/enhance" the base baseQuery API slice. You only need to add one API slice per base query. Whatever API slice you import to use in the store should already have the split API slices injected into them.
Example:
baseQuery.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const baseQuery = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    prepareHeaders: headers => {
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
      return headers;
    }
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  reducerPath: 'api',
  tagTypes: [
    'comments',
    'posts'
  ]
});

postApi.js: Imports the baseQuery API slice, and exports an enhanced version.
import { baseQuery } from './baseQuery';

const enhancedBaseQuery = baseQuery.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: ({ mutation, query }) => ({
    addPost: mutation({
      invalidatesTags: ['posts'],
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/posts`
      })
    }),
    getPosts: query({
      providesTags: ['posts'],
      query: () => `/posts`
    }),
  })
})

export const {
  useAddPostMutation,
  useGetPostsQuery
} = enhancedBaseQuery;

export default enhancedBaseQuery;

commentsApi.js: Should import the enhanced API slice from postsApi.js, and export another enhanced API slice version.
import baseQuery from 'api/postApi';

const enhancedBaseQuery = baseQuery.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: ({ mutation, query }) => ({
    getComments: query({
      providesTags: ['comments'],
      query: () => `/posts/1/comments`
    }),
  })
});

export const {
  useGetCommentsQuery
} = BaseQuery;

export default BaseQuery;

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

// API
import baseQuery from 'api/commentsApi';

const reducer = {
  [baseQuery.reducerPath]: baseQuery.reducer,
};

const middleware = getDefaultMiddleware =>
  getDefaultMiddleware()
    .concat(baseQuery.middleware);

export const store = configureStore({
  middleware,
  reducer
});

Alternative
What I've typically done previously is to export just the endpoint definitions from the split code and inject them in the file/component creating the root baseQueryAPI slice.
Example:
baseQuery.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { commentsApi } from 'api/commentsApi'
import { postApi } from 'api/postApi'

export const baseQuery = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    prepareHeaders: headers => {
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
      return headers
    }
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  reducerPath: 'api',
  tagTypes: [
    'comments',
    'posts'
  ]
});

postApi.js

export const postApi = {
  endpoints: ({ mutation, query }) => ({
    addPost: mutation({
      invalidatesTags: ['posts'],
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/posts`
      })
    }),
    getPosts: query({
      providesTags: ['posts'],
      query: () => `/posts`
    }),
  })
};

commentsApi.js
export const commentsApi = {
  endpoints: ({ mutation, query }) => ({
    getComments: query({
      providesTags: ['comments'],
      query: () => `/posts/1/comments`
    }),
  })
};

store
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

// API
import { baseQuery } from 'api/baseQuery';
import { commentsApi } from 'api/commentsApi';
import { postApi } from 'api/postApi';

const apiSlice = baseQuery
  .injectEndpoints(commentsApi)
  .injectEndpoints(postApi);

const reducer = {
  [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
}

const middleware = getDefaultMiddleware =>
  getDefaultMiddleware()
    .concat(apiSlice.middleware)

export const store = configureStore({
  middleware,
  reducer
});

export const {
  // ... all the generated hooks ...
} = apiSlice;


Yep, they didn't mention this change in a newer version of RTK when updating, had looked through a number of issues on Github that now mention this.
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/4236#issuecomment-1976018982
Seems like an oversite they missed on new updates.

@T.Evans Interesting. I thought by the injectEndpoints function signature returning a new API slice (e.g. EnhancedApiSlice) that it was obvious to use the new one, e.g. to chain from them. I suppose the "injectEndpoints" name could be confusing if you didn't realize this though and thought you were augmenting the original.

Yeah, well its a thing now for devs to know now that injectEndpoints is now just to be chained to one api reducer. Hopefully this helps out a few people in the future!! Thanks for your help!
